# Simple UDP socket in VC++ MFC

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, mfc, udp, textbox

I have been trying to write a working program that takes in data from a UDP socket and displays it in an edit control box as you receive the data (My exposure to c++ is also only about a week :P have only done embedded C code before). I have a working program that can send and output data on a button click but I want something that can do it in real time. The aim is scale this up into a larger GUI program that can send control data to hardware and get responses from them.

I have run into various problems including:

1. The program just not executing my `OnReceive`function (derived from
   `CAsyncSocket`)
2. Getting the `OnReceive` function to run on a separate thread so that it can still run after a button has been clicked sending a control packet to the client then waiting for a response in a while loop
3. Not being able to output the data in the edit box (tried using both `CEdit` and `CString`)
4. `ReplaceSel` error saying that the type `char` is incompatible with `LPCTSTR`

My code is based on [this codeproject.com tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26715/Simple-client-server-UDP-socket-program), being almost exactly what I want but I get the error in 4.

EDIT: the error in 4. disappears when I change it to a `TCHAR` but then it outputs random chinese characters. The codeproject.com tutorial outputs the correct characters regardless of `char` or `TCHAR` declaration. When debugged my code has type `wchar_t` instead type `char` like the other code.

[Chinese output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kBAM.png)

In the working program `echoBuffer[0]` the character sent and displayed was a `1`

```
UINT ReceiveData(LPVOID pParam)
{
    CTesterDlg *dlg = (CTesterDlg*)pParam;
    AfxSocketInit(NULL);
    CSocket echoServer;

    // Create socket for sending/receiving datagrams
    if (echoServer.Create(12345, SOCK_DGRAM, NULL) == 0) 
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Create() failed"));
    }

    for (;;) 
    { // Run forever

        // Client address
        SOCKADDR_IN echoClntAddr;

        // Set the size of the in-out parameter
        int clntAddrLen = sizeof(echoClntAddr);

        // Buffer for echo string
        char echoBuffer[ECHOMAX];

        // Block until receive message from a client
        int recvMsgSize = echoServer.ReceiveFrom(echoBuffer, ECHOMAX, (SOCKADDR*)&echoClntAddr, &clntAddrLen, 0);
        if (recvMsgSize < 0)
        {
            AfxMessageBox(_T("RecvFrom() failed"));
        }

        echoBuffer[recvMsgSize] = '\0';

        dlg->m_edit.ReplaceSel(echoBuffer);
        dlg->m_edit.ReplaceSel(_T("\r\n"));


    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, you are doing it wrong. We cannot help you, unless you show the code. Provide a [mcve] to make this question useful (see also [ask]).

Comment: @IInspectable I have added code and a debug image.

Comment: *"the error in 4. disappears when I change it to a `TCHAR` but then it outputs random chinese characters."* Please read [working with strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407.aspx) and [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the link that @IInspectable provided about working with strings and checking the settings differences between the two programs it became clear that the issue lay with an incorrect conversion to UNICODE. My program does not require it so I disabled it.

This has cleared up the issue in 4. and provided solutions for 2 and 3.
I also think I know why another instance of my program would not run `OnReceive`in 1. because that file was not being defined by one that was already being run by the program, but that is now irrelevant.